How to add new data and run again after running in Backtrader?
How to add new data and run again after running in Backtrader?
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    data = bt.feeds.PandasData(
        dataname=df
    )

    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.addstrategy(MyStrategy)

    cerebro.addanalyzer(TradeAnalyzer)
    cerebro.addanalyzer(Returns)
    cerebro.addanalyzer(AnnualReturn)

    bt_result = cerebro.run()
    
    final_value = cerebro.broker.getvalue()

    # get some metrics with bt_result[0].analyzers 

    # How to add new data here and continue run backtest with new data?

I can't find the relevant API in the documentation
